# Filling in NULL values in SQL with a string

Tags: sql, database, string

I have a table of animals:

```
AnimalID | Name   
2          George  
4  
5          Pete  
6
```

I want to fill in the NULL values where the animals have no names with a string called "No Name"

Help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to do that? In Select, Insert statement?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE animals
SET name = 'No Name'
WHERE name IS NULL or name = ''
```

Comment: `"No Name"` is not a string it's a column name in (standard) SQL (and the DBMS in use has not been disclosed yet)